Issue with Flipping Views in UIStackView based on Condition
In my iOS project, I'm working with a UIStackView that contains multiple subviews. I want to dynamically flip or move up and down specific views within the stack view based on a condition. Specifically,
I'm attempting to manipulate the positions of two text fields named FIRST and SECOND. However, I'm encountering an issue where the flipping only works correctly on every second tap or click.
Here is my code for the same
import UIKit
import Combine

import SnapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private var toggleSubject = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()
    private var toggle = false
    private var store = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    private lazy var topField: AppTextField = {
        let view = AppTextField(title: "First")
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var bottomField: AppTextField = {
        let view = AppTextField(title: "Second")
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var lineView: UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let view = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [topField, lineView, bottomField, toggleButton])
        view.axis  = .vertical
        view.spacing = 4.0
        view.distribution = .fill
        view.alignment = .fill
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var toggleButton: UIButton = {
        let view = UIButton(frame: .zero)
        view.setTitle("Toggle", for: .normal)
        view.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        view.setTitleColor(.systemYellow, for: .highlighted)
        view.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    
    private lazy var selectedTopFieldLabel: UILabel = {
        let view = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        view.textAlignment = .center
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(stackView)
        self.view.addSubview(selectedTopFieldLabel)
        toggleSubject.send(toggle)
        
        stackView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.trailing.centerY.equalToSuperview().inset(16)
        }
        
        lineView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.height.equalTo(0.5)
        }
        
        selectedTopFieldLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(200)
        }
        
        
        toggleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        toggleSubject.sink { toggle in
            print("---> Changed Toggle",toggle)
            self.updateUI(toggle: toggle)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
                self.stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }.store(in: &store)
        self.updateUI(toggle: toggle)
    }
    
    @objc func toggleButtonAction() {
        toggle.toggle()
        toggleSubject.send(toggle)
    }
    
    private func updateUI(toggle: Bool) {
        let arrangedSubviews = self.stackView.arrangedSubviews
        
        guard var first = arrangedSubviews[0] as? AppTextField,
              var second = arrangedSubviews[2] as? AppTextField else {return}
        stackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach({$0.removeFromSuperview()})
        let changedViews = toggle ? [first, lineView, second, toggleButton] : [second, lineView, first , toggleButton]

        guard let firstTextField = changedViews.first as? AppTextField,
              let firstfieldPlaceholder = firstTextField.placeholder else {return}

        self.selectedTopFieldLabel.text =  "Selected On Top " + " -> " + firstfieldPlaceholder

        changedViews.forEach { view in
            self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
        }
        // Update constraints
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.stackView.setNeedsLayout()
            self.stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}

class AppTextField: UIView {
    
    private lazy var inputField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.backgroundColor = .lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.15)
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return textField
    }()
    
    
    var title: String? {
        get { return inputField.placeholder }
        set { inputField.placeholder = newValue }
    }
    
    var placeholder: String? {
        get { return inputField.placeholder }
        set { inputField.placeholder = newValue }
    }
    
    var text: String? {
        get { return inputField.text }
        set { inputField.text = newValue }
    }
    
    init(title: String) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        self.title = title
        setupViews()
    }
    
    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func setupViews() {
        addSubview(inputField)
        inputField.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(48)
        }
    }
}


Thanks in advance.

Can you add missing AppTextField code for reproducing purposes?

The problem is your logic...
When you tap the button, you toggle toggle between True and False
Then you call updateUI(toggle: toggle), at which point this code:
let changedViews = toggle ? [first, lineView, second, toggleButton] : [second, lineView, first , toggleButton]

Says:

If toggle is True

don't change the order


else

change the order



Which means your button taps are saying:

change the order
don't change the order
change the order
don't change the order
etc

So, if your goal is to change the order on every button tap, you don't need the toggle bool var at all. Change your UI update to this:
private func updateUI() {
    let arrangedSubviews = self.stackView.arrangedSubviews
    
    guard let first = arrangedSubviews[0] as? AppTextField,
          let second = arrangedSubviews[2] as? AppTextField else {return}
    
    let changedViews = [second, lineView, first , toggleButton]
    
    guard let firstTextField = changedViews.first as? AppTextField,
          let firstfieldPlaceholder = firstTextField.placeholder else {return}
    
    self.selectedTopFieldLabel.text =  "Selected On Top " + " -> " + firstfieldPlaceholder
    
    changedViews.forEach { view in
        self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
    }
    // Update constraints
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
        self.stackView.setNeedsLayout()
        self.stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

and call it without the bool:
self.updateUI()

Or, if your goal is to set the order based on a Bool var, you might change your code to this:
private func updateUI(firstOnTop: Bool) {
    let changedViews = firstOnTop ? [self.topField, lineView, self.bottomField, toggleButton] : [self.bottomField, lineView, self.topField , toggleButton]
    
    guard let firstTextField = changedViews.first as? AppTextField,
          let firstfieldPlaceholder = firstTextField.placeholder else {return}
    
    self.selectedTopFieldLabel.text =  "Selected On Top " + " -> " + firstfieldPlaceholder
    
    changedViews.forEach { view in
        self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
    }
    // Update constraints
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
        self.stackView.setNeedsLayout()
        self.stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

and call it like this:
self.updateUI(firstOnTop: toggle)


I could change the code above to

Using CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(false) instead to avoid extra Bool variable
StackView can addArrangedSubview without removing sub views then re-adding again


The toggle action should be:
private var toggleSubject = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(false)
@objc func toggleButtonAction() {
    toggleSubject.value.toggle()
}

...
//Keep toggleSubject sink as it was
toggleSubject
    .sink { [weak self] toggle in
        self?.updateUI(toggle: toggle)
    }
    .store(in: &store)

Then remove other stuff in updateUI:
private func updateUI(toggle: Bool) {
    if toggle {
        self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(topField)
        self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(lineView)
        self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(bottomField)
        self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(toggleButton)
    } else {
        self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(bottomField)
        self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(lineView)
        self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(topField)
        self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(toggleButton)
    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
        self.stackView.setNeedsLayout()
        self.stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

Output


Update: Since you wanted to keep your current code, I updated the answer to this approach below. The root problem is you remained arrangedSubviews at index 0 and 2 even when these AppTextField swapped each other, the indices need to swap too:
...
let firstIndex = toggle ? 0 : 2
let secondIndex = toggle ? 2 : 0
guard let first = arrangedSubviews[firstIndex] as? AppTextField,
      let second = arrangedSubviews[secondIndex] as? AppTextField else { return }
...


Yeah, I know this can be one solution. But need solutions without by using existing views

The views are still the same. I didn't add another, It's just a trimmed version of unnecessary code. What I want to mention is removeFromSuperview and then addArrangedSubview is an inefficient way.

I trying to find a solution to rearrange views without introducing new code, so the idea is how to rearrange views with minimal code change @soniem

Ok I updated the answer, you may want to take a look.

Thanks this worked for me
private func updateUI(toggle: Bool) {
        let arrangedSubviews = self.stackView.arrangedSubviews
        
        let fromIndex = toggle ? 0 : 2
        let toIndex = toggle ? 2 : 0
               guard let first = arrangedSubviews[fromIndex] as? AppTextField,
              let second = arrangedSubviews[toIndex] as? AppTextField else {return}
      
....


Your problem is in this line
let changedViews = toggle ? [first, lineView, second, toggleButton] : [second, lineView, first , toggleButton]

It accesses the same item and put it again in same place because of
the ternary operator , you already swap them by  accessing the indices so change it to
let changedViews = [second, lineView, first , toggleButton]

Full Edit:

import UIKit
import Combine

import SnapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private var toggleSubject = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()
    private var toggle = false
    private var store = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    private lazy var topField: AppTextField = {
        let view = AppTextField(title: "First")
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var bottomField: AppTextField = {
        let view = AppTextField(title: "Second")
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var lineView: UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let view = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [topField, lineView, bottomField, toggleButton])
        view.axis  = .vertical
        view.spacing = 4.0
        view.distribution = .fill
        view.alignment = .fill
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var toggleButton: UIButton = {
        let view = UIButton(frame: .zero)
        view.setTitle("Toggle", for: .normal)
        view.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        view.setTitleColor(.systemYellow, for: .highlighted)
        view.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    
    private lazy var selectedTopFieldLabel: UILabel = {
        let view = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        view.textAlignment = .center
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(stackView)
        self.view.addSubview(selectedTopFieldLabel)
        toggleSubject.send(toggle)
        
        stackView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.trailing.centerY.equalToSuperview().inset(16)
        }
        
        lineView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.height.equalTo(0.5)
        }
        
        selectedTopFieldLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(200)
        }
        
        
        toggleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        toggleSubject.sink { toggle in
            print("---> Changed Toggle",toggle)
            self.updateUI(toggle: toggle)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
                self.stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }.store(in: &store)
        self.updateUI(toggle: toggle)
    }
    
    @objc func toggleButtonAction() {
        toggle.toggle()
        toggleSubject.send(toggle)
    }
    
    private func updateUI(toggle: Bool) {
        let arrangedSubviews = self.stackView.arrangedSubviews
        
        guard let first = arrangedSubviews[0] as? AppTextField,
              let second = arrangedSubviews[2] as? AppTextField else {return}
        stackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach({$0.removeFromSuperview()})
        let changedViews = [second, lineView, first , toggleButton]

        guard let firstTextField = changedViews.first as? AppTextField,
              let firstfieldPlaceholder = firstTextField.placeholder else {return}

        self.selectedTopFieldLabel.text =  "Selected On Top " + " -> " + firstfieldPlaceholder

        changedViews.forEach { view in
            self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
        }
        // Update constraints
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.stackView.setNeedsLayout()
            self.stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}

class AppTextField: UIView {
    
    private lazy var inputField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.backgroundColor = .lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.15)
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return textField
    }()
    
    
    var title: String? {
        get { return inputField.placeholder }
        set { inputField.placeholder = newValue }
    }
    
    var placeholder: String? {
        get { return inputField.placeholder }
        set { inputField.placeholder = newValue }
    }
    
    var text: String? {
        get { return inputField.text }
        set { inputField.text = newValue }
    }
    
    init(title: String) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        self.title = title
        setupViews()
    }
    
    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func setupViews() {
        addSubview(inputField)
        inputField.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(48)
        }
    }
}




nope, even not worked .. you can try my code.
